# Can not access ndk-bundle in Mac

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Mac, I just installed `NDK`, that looks been installed at:
`/Users/${user}/library/android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570`

Once I tried to go deeper inside the `ndk-build` I get the error:`no such file or directory`

I need to generate a toolchain, and remember I did it before as:

```sh
${NDK_HOME}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 28 --arch x86_64 --install-dir NDK/x86_64
```

Where `NDK_HOME` was `ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

[image]

**UPDATE**

Reading [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems), I changed the `NDK_HOME` to be `/Users/hasan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/` and run the command as:

```sh
hasan$ ${NDK_HOME}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/clang++ -target armv7a-linux-androideabi NDK/armv7a
```

But got the same error:

```sh
-bash: /Users/hasan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570//toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/clang++: No such file or directory
```

Comment: in my mac, it is, `/Users/hello/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`

Comment: @TouhidulIslam in my Mac, folder named `ndk` had been created inside the `sdk` as shown in the screenshoot provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks with NDK19+ the linker are coming prebuilt, and can be accessed as:

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "/Users/hajsf/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "/Users/hajsf/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android23-clang"
```

where the linker should include the `minSdkVersion` for example `x86_64-linux-android23-clang` means `minSdkVersion` is `API 23`

Note: NDK can be downloaded from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21-darwin-x86_64.zip, or can be installed from Android Studio, and it will be added to `SDK path: /Users/hasan/Library/Android/sdk`

[image]